# iOS 8 UINavigationBar Background Image

Tags: xcode, ios8

I'm using de following code for placing an image on the background of the UINavigation Bar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background_login.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In iOS 7 works like a charm but when I try it in the same simulator device but with iOS 8 the background image doesn't show.

There is some new code for iOS 8? I can't find anything on the net.

---

UPDATE:

I've discovered one of the most weird behaviors I've ever seen.
When I show and later dismiss a modalView, then the Background Image of the UINavigationBar appears.

For more information: I'm loading the image in the viewDidLoad.

Any thoughs?

Comment: Outdated duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602848/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this it worked for me:-

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background_login.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It worked perfect!! I can believe I didn't tried that.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background_login.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; 
write this in your app delegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method it will set the nav bar background image app wide.

Comment: For a better solution and different screen sizes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602848/

Answer (score 2):

Using `[UINavigationBar appearance]` to set the UINavigationBar background globally is correct. But please note that **the appearance affects only the future instances but not the already created ones.** Try to place the set appearance code some place before your UINavigationConroller is created. it should still work.